# MSI Bios written to During Installation of Ubuntu Cinnamon 22.04

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, bios, cinnamon

System = MSI B450-A PRO MAX, Ryzen 7 5700G and 32gb ram. Trying to install O/S on my system but it locked up. Some how, In process it seems my Bios got Corrupted. I've tried several times to get into the Bios, even changing my CPU to Ryzen 5 3700 with no graphics and even no hard drive, but I cannot access Bios to reset boot order and one of the Ubuntu Cinnamon screen displays and is locked or frozen. It seems the Bios is corrupted.
I cannot do anything.
Anyone have any issues like this?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available from MSI? And if NVMe updated SSD firmware? If UEFI fast start up on, it assumes no system changes & immediately boots into (old) configuration. You should be able to do a full power down/cold boot. Drain all power after disconnecting from mains by holding power switch. Then boot & immediately press correct key to get into UEFI settings, varies by vendor.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *The first official [launch of Ubuntu Cinnamon was 23.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue781#Ubuntu_Cinnamon_for_Official_Flavor_Status); you're using a remix and not Ubuntu created ISO*

Comment: No one the updates. However, there is only 1.CPU, 1.Stick of Ram and 1.Video card. No SSD or harddrives. Still that locked Ubuntu.Cinnamon screen appears.  I cannot 
 access BIIOS by delete.  Any suggestions???